# Ruby Encrypt-Decrypt exercise using ARGV

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, base64

I started recently learning Ruby and I got an assignment as described here:

[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPQUE.png)

So far this is my code, and the encode is working but the decode doesn't.
I tried search on google for answer and didn't find one, most likely I don't have enough experience to understand some of the things I found.
The only thing I know is that the key, after I enter the output of the encode is too big as an error message said.

I hope someone can help me understand what's wrong.

```
 #!/usr/bin/ruby

require "openssl"
require "base64"
include Base64

# check if argv is empty or if argv contains more than two values. if so, print error message and exit program
if ARGV.empty? || ARGV.length > 2
  puts "Error: invalid input, please try again."
  exit(2)
end

# check which method need - encrypt (ARGV contains only one value) of decrypt (ARGV contains two values)
if ARGV.length == 1

   # create the cipher for encrypting
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:CBC)
  cipher.encrypt

  text = ARGV[0].to_s
  key = cipher.random_key
  iv = cipher.random_iv

  # Encrypt the data, print it and exit program
  cipher_text = cipher.update(text) + cipher.final
  puts "\"" + urlsafe_encode64(cipher_text) + "\"  \"" + urlsafe_encode64(key) + "\""
  exit(2)
end

# check which method need - encrypt (ARGV contains only one value) of decrypt (ARGV contains two values)
if ARGV.length == 2                                                   

  # create the cipher decrypt
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:CBC)
  decipher.decrypt

  decrypt_text = ARGV[0].to_s
  decipher.key = ARGV[1].to_s
  decipher.iv = decipher.random_iv

  # Decrypt the data, print it and exit program
  decrypted_text = decipher.update(decrypt_text) + decipher.final
  puts "\"" + decrypted_text + "\""
  exit(2)
end
```

Comment: your code doesn't raise any errors when i run it ,  you just need to specify one argument.
`ruby yourcode.rb test` => `"8NuL1fbm5W6s4b4Sk4UJTA=="  "T_h31m0QwG53XT7cqF-62w=="`
What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific; tell us how exactly the program behaves differently from what you expect, and include any error messages you may be getting as well. Knowing what command line you run the program with (specially what arguments) may also be useful for reproducing the problem.

Comment: when I encode it works fine but when I decode I get error message about the size of the key. I tried now to find some way to decode base 64 the key and text before I decipher them but I still got error message after that on line 44 ("update key not set <OpenSSL:Cipher:CipherError> from encode_decode.rb:44in <main>)

and I don't know how to raise errors, I'm still new to ruby but because it's similar to Python I understand the basic.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem I notice is that when encrypting, you encode the ciphertext and key in base64, but then in the decryption step you don't decode them back into text/binary data.

Try fixing that and see if it works after that :)

Another weird thing I noticed is the line `iv = cipher.random_iv`. I suppose you meant something similar to `decipher.iv = decipher.random_iv` a few lines below.

To help avoid simple mistakes like this, always run `ruby -wc <your_program.rb>` to have ruby check the syntax of the file. In the case above, it would have told you that the variable `iv` is declared but never used. (`-c` = check syntax only; `-w` = show warnings as well as errors)

Comment: I'm new to this and I can't find in stackoverflow solution to how to decrypt. do you have any websites with information on how to do it? I found only encrypting with base64

and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: base64 is used for encoding, you can't hide data with it, it's no encryption.
encrypting in your program is done with AES

Comment: I did what you said about -wc and in both cases (encode and decode) it wrote "Syntax OK"

I tried to decode the base64 code and still get error but different. I'll edit the post so you can see the update

Comment: what method do I use to decode the base64 I used on the key?